# Problems with pointers in a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic

I need some help. My program crashes when I try to input data and save it to a pointer. I can successfully input data to the first element of dynamic array, I can even print that data. However, after that, when I try to input the second element, my program crashes. The debugger doesn't show any errors or warnings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

static const char SPRTR[] = "//---------------------------------------------------------------------------//";
static const char ERR_MSG[] = "ERROR! Try again.";

void create_array(int **data, int *n, int *arr_max)
{
    int i;
    int err;
    char temp;

    do
    {
        err = 0;
        printf("\nMaximum number of array elements: ");
        if (((scanf("%d", arr_max)) < 1) || (*arr_max <= 0))
        {
            printf("%s\n", ERR_MSG);
            err = 1;
        }
        printf("\n%s\n", SPRTR);
        while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);
    } while (err != 0);

    do
    {
        err = 0;
        printf("\nNumber of array elements (max. %d): ", *arr_max);
        if (((scanf("%d", n)) < 1) || (*n > *arr_max) || (*n <= 0))
        {
            printf("%s\n", ERR_MSG);
            err = 1;
        }
        printf("\n%s\n", SPRTR);
        while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);
    } while (err != 0);

    *data = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * (*n));

    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            err = 0;
            printf("\nValue of %d array element: ", i);
            if (((scanf("%d", *(data + i))) < 1) || (*(*(data + i)) < 0))
            {
                printf("%s\n", ERR_MSG);
                printf("\n%s\n", SPRTR);
                err = 1;
            }
            while ((temp = getchar()) != '\n' && temp != EOF);
        } while (err != 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    int arr_max;
    int *data;

    create_array(&data, &n, &arr_max);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Debugger............................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler (and also mine) don't find errors because you use the correct types, yet there are two errors (actually twice the same error) in this statement:

```
if (((scanf("%d", *(data + i))) < 1) || (*(*(data + i)) < 0))
```

`data` is the pointer (the address) to your `int *` holding the result of your `malloc`.
So the `int`s you could access to are `(*data)[i]` and their addresses are `*data + i`. So this line should be replaced by:

```
if (((scanf("%d", *data + i)) < 1) || ((*data)[i] < 0))
```

At least it works for me.

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful because I'm new to C language (and programming overall) and sometimes pointers and adresses can be confusing for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the line

```
if (((scanf("%d", *(data + i))) < 1) || (*(*(data + i)) < 0))
```

You should be dereferencing data to obtain the pointer to the current element
and then adding the offset, instead you dereference a location which is not a pointer to the array itself.

Try replacing 
*(data + i) with *data + i so then if statement becomes:

```
if (((scanf("%d", *data + i)) < 1) || ((*(*data + i)) < 0))
```

Also *(*data + i)) is just obtaining the offset of the array so this can be replaced with (*data)[i], so the if statement then becomes:

```
if (((scanf("%d", *data + i)) < 1) || ((*data)[i] < 0))
```